# List files from the root folder with onedrive Android API

Tags: android, onedrive

I'm using OneDrive in an Android App and I can't find how to list the root folder contents.

I'm using the [LiveSDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn631814.aspx)

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can issue a request against the users root OneDrive folder at me/skydrive/files

```
GET https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/skydrive/files HTTP/1.1
Authorization: bearer EwCIAq...
Host: apis.live.net
```

If you were using the [LiveSDK for Android](https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK-for-android) then your code would need to look something like this once you'd setup your LiveConnectClient running.

```
 mClient.getAsync("me/skydrive/files", new LiveOperationListener() {

     @Override
     public void OnComplete(LiveOperation operation) {
         JSONObject result = operation.getResult();
         // Use this information to update your application
     }

 });
```

To see a copy of this code running you can look into the sample [Android Application for its implementation](https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK-for-Android/blob/master/sample/src/com/microsoft/live/sample/skydrive/SkyDriveActivity.java#L759).